# Entity Framework designer does not update from database

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I get a error "Unexpected Error ... The DLL "SQLite.Interop.dll": The module could was not found (Exception HRESULT: 0x8007007E) could not be loaded" (It's not exctly what it says, I translated it from German). The application can build and run perfectly I am just not able to make the EF Designer update the model from the database. It's Visual Studio Pro 2015 and the System.Data.SQLite stuff is installed using NuGet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used SysInternals ProcessMonitor To find out, that the missing dll is searched in the folder

"C:\Users#Username#\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ProjectAssemblies#A cryptic name#\x86".

Copied the "SQLite.Interop.dll" into that folder and voila, it worked...

Comment: It's only a temporary solution, next time that I tried it was not working again.